# Class requires API level 21 (current min is 19): android.hardware.camera2.CameraDevice.StateCallback

Tags: android, android-camera2

i want to use texture view only.
Now i know about the texture view what is this but i see the video on youtube and do same as in video.
but i have a problem with Api level.

So help me.
Infect don't know about the api level what is this how it is important

```
TextureView.SurfaceTextureListener textureListener = new   TextureView.SurfaceTextureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onSurfaceTextureAvailable(SurfaceTexture surface, int width, int height) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "texture is available", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onSurfaceTextureSizeChanged(SurfaceTexture surface, int width, int height) {

        }

        @Override
        public boolean onSurfaceTextureDestroyed(SurfaceTexture surface) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public void onSurfaceTextureUpdated(SurfaceTexture surface) {

        }
    };
    private CameraDevice cameraDevice;
    private CameraDevice.StateCallback stateCallback = new CameraDevice.StateCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onOpened( CameraDevice camera) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onDisconnected( CameraDevice camera) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onError( CameraDevice camera, int error) {

        }
    }
```

Comment: You must change your `minSdkVersion` in gradle file from 19 to 21, then Sync your project.

Comment: Understand that doing what @Tommy says will stop you from running on Android v4.4 (Kitkat).  To keep KitKat as your minimum version, you need to either not use the camera2 apis at all, or use them only if your version number is high enough and drop the feature if not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [android doc](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/package-summary) camera2 api added from api level 21. so you can't use it android version below 21

You'll need camera2 (when devices that support fast, full-resolution capture - see the [BURST_CAPTURE](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CameraMetadata.html#REQUEST_AVAILABLE_CAPABILITIES_BURST_CAPTURE) capability, or any device that supports the [FULL](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CameraMetadata.html#INFO_SUPPORTED_HARDWARE_LEVEL_FULL) hardware level.), if you want bursts at resolutions above ~1080p.

if you are targeting only Simple capture photos and videos, The old camera API will work fine

You can check with the [**CameraView**](https://github.com/google/cameraview) unofficial support library, and modify it as needed. It has support for both APIs, selected based on API level of the device

there is [**CameraView**](https://github.com/natario1/CameraView) from natario1, [**Fotoapparat**](https://github.com/RedApparat/Fotoapparat) from RedApparat, [**camerakit-android**](https://github.com/CameraKit/camerakit-android), etc 3rd party library in your senario